# Transaction and error handling - `statement_timeout`

Tags: postgresql

I am trying to create very simple transaction which will set timeout for a single query.

The transaction looks like:

```
BEGIN;
SET LOCAL statement_timeout TO 8000;
SELECT pg_sleep(8);
COMMIT;
```

When I run it throws exception as expected

```
sql> BEGIN
[2019-01-25 09:36:01] completed in 2 ms
sql> SET LOCAL statement_timeout TO 8000
[2019-01-25 09:36:01] completed in 3 ms
sql> SELECT pg_sleep(8)
[2019-01-25 09:36:10] [57014] ERROR: canceling statement due to statement timeout
```

but I am unable to run another query. I need to run manually `ROLLBACK;`

```
sql> SELECT 1
[2019-01-25 09:38:21] [25P02] ERROR: current transaction is aborted, commands ignored until end of transaction block
[2019-01-25 09:38:21] [57014] ERROR: canceling statement due to statement timeout
```

Is it possible to somehow catch the exception and do ROLLBACK in transaction explicitly? I thought this handles the database engine.

Comment: I think that documentation page is for you : https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-control-structures.html#PLPGSQL-ERROR-TRAPPING